# fadeIn not working with a change effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, select, input

I have the function `fadeBoolToggle` which checks to see if a condition is true and then fades in the element, if not, it will then fadeout/not show.

The code is working for the most part, except for one critical part. If you check both `package 1` and `package 2`. It initially performs correctly, only the header `Package 1` shows, but what I want to happen is after a select option is selected, `Package 2` should fade in.

So the initial part of this is correct..

[image]

But then when a select is chosen, the code is not working how I want it to. With any selection (when package 1 and 2 are both chosen), package 2 should fade in...

[image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqm4ttbp/1/)

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
$('.product-check').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#pg-selection').show();
    $('#tp-selection').hide();
    //$('#tp-selection').fadeBoolToggle($('#calendar-preview-select option:selected').length > 0);
  } else if ($('#package2').not(':checked') && $('#package1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#pg-selection').show();
    $('#tp-selection').hide();
  } else if ($('#package1').not(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#tp-selection').show();
    $('#pg-selection').hide();
  }
});

$('#calendar-preview-select').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#calendar-preview-select option:selected')) {
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#calendar-preview-select').offset().top - 10
    }, 800);
    if ($('#package1').prop('checked') && $('#package2').prop('checked')) {
      $('#tp-selection').fadeBoolToggle($('#calendar-preview-select option:selected').length > 0);
       //$('#tp-selection').show();
      $('#next2').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#pg-selection,
#tp-selection {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Section 1 -->
<label>Package 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package1">
<label>Package 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package2">
<!-- Section 2 -->
<div id="pg-selection" class="package-setup">
  <h2>Package 1 Section</h2>
  <select id="calendar-preview-select" class="option-input">
    <option value='' disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
    <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="tp-selection" class="package-setup">
  <h2>Package 2 Section</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see the error in the snippet. It's because there's no `#pg-preview-wrap` element, hence `offset().top` is undefined

Comment: Your `fiddle console` says there is no element with `id` - `#pg-preview-wrap` and you are trying to `animate` the `html,body` to its `top` position which is undefined and hence the execution stops there. So, either check out for that element and define it or remove that. Rest everything looks good.

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nqm4ttbp/4/)**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Missed changing that from my actual code. That error is not present in my actual code and I changed my question. My actual code is in the same format, but this does not work for it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that most do not like looking at a bunch of code, so I tried recreating it as simple as I could. Here is some of the actual code. You can see within it that this doesn't work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWrWyp?editors=0000